# polynomial remainder problem

Tags: polynomials

If a polynomial $f(x)$, of degree at least four, is such that
$$f(x) \equiv 3x+1 \mod (x^{2}-1)$$
and
$$f(x) \equiv 2x-3\mod (x^{2}+1),$$
find the remainder $g(x)$ such that
$$f(x) \equiv g(x) \mod (x^{2}-1)(x^{2}+1).$$

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @quid: Thanks. I am aware of the name but not of the thing under the name. Thanks for a clue. I am checking that, which is not a part of my working knowledge :)

Comment: @quid: Would you like to write up a proof, even a sketch if time does not allow.

Comment: I wrote something. Double check the calculations though; the method is definitely sound. I am a rubbish-computer with such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main steps are:

- We note that $\frac{1}{2} (x^2 + 1) - \frac{1}{2} (x^2 - 1)  = 1$.
- Thus the inverse of $x^2 + 1  \mod x^2 -1$ is $1/2$ and the inverse of  $x^2 - 1  \mod x^2 +1$ is $-1/2$.
- Thus a solution is $(3x+ 1) \frac{x^2 + 1}{2} + (2x-3) (-\frac{x^2 - 1}{2}) $.

The first step can be done in a more systematic way using the extended Euclidean algorithm. The general method is the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) for polynomials.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not sure of what the "inverse" here means?

Comment: A modular inverse  of $a \mod b$ is an element $c$ such that $ac $ is $1$ $\mod b$. Observe that $\frac{1}{2} (x^2 + 1) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(x^2 - 1)$ so $\frac{1}{2} (x^2 + 1)$ is $1$ mod $x^2 - 1$

Comment: Pardon me. I do not see a way to go from the second to the third. Does it have something to do with the Chinese Remainder Theorem? Appreciated.

Comment: Yes it does;see the page I linked. Howver to see it directly jjust note that $a \frac{x^2 + 1}{2} + b (-\frac{x^2 - 1}{2}) $ is $a$ mod $x^2 - 1 $ and $b$ mod $x^2 + 1$ as $\frac{x^2 + 1}{2}$ is then $1$ and $0$ respectively and conversely for $-\frac{x^2 - 1}{2}$ .

Comment: Ah Ha! Thanks very much. Finally I get the idea. :)